# SQLCMD batch file error

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

This is sample T-SQL code that I saved in file named `test.log`:

```
insert into [TESTDB].[dbo].[TESTTABLE] 
values (4759999, 201511, 6241810, -1, 1, 61.2675, 171.2915, 235.0000)
```

Then I created a `.bat` file with this content:

```
FOR %%x IN (*.log) DO OSQL -U test -P XXXX -S testserver -d testDB -i "%%x" >> Log.txt
```

and I saved this file as `test.bat`.

When I excuted this, it throws the following error

> can't find stored procedure i

Please help.

Note: My OS is Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: You should - as you made believe in the title - use the `SQLCMD` utility - not `osql` or `isql`, those are deprecated

Comment: I used SQLCMD also, still same error